# JQuery Tree Traversal - Goes Up Tree but not Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, traversal

I am trying to traverse up the tree from the script tag using `$(document.currentScript)` and then traverse back down the tree, selecting the input element. I have tried many variations of going down the tree but they all don't seem to work. I was able to get the top div, `$(document.currentScript).closest("div").parent("div")` but have no luck going down

```
<div id="p9t2c13">
   <div class="control">
      <label for="c13">
         <h3> HiddenInstanceId </h3>
         <p>
            <script>
               if (typeof counter == "undefined") {
                  counter = 0;
               }

               counter++;

               var test = $(document.currentScript).closest("div").parent("div");
               console.log($(test).find("input"))
            </script>
         </p>
      </label>
      <p class="ctrlinvalidmessage"></p>
      <fieldset>
         <div class="input text">
            <input id="c13" type="text" name="c13" value="" maxlength="1000">
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does console.log(test); return?

Comment: It returns `[div#p9t2c13, prevObject: init[1], context: script, selector: ".closest(div).parent(div)"]` and references to the correct object but not the below `<input/>` tag that I'm looking for

Comment: [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)It's important to note that this will not reference the <script> element if the code in the script is being called as a callback or event handler; it will only reference the element while it's initially being processed.

Ok, but it is neither a callback or event handler...hmm..

Comment: Would there be a way around this?

Comment: Never used these property before, but if you wrap it into `$()` you don't get a reference to the wrapped jQuery element:
`console.log($(document.currentScript).size());` outputs:
`"TypeError: $(...).size is not a function`

Comment: It's not picking up the input - I think it has something to do with the DOM being ready. If I put the input before the `.control` element, it finds the input - I can even change the input value using `test.find('input').val('test');`. If, however, I add the document load wrapper `$(function() { /* code here */ }`, then it's being used as a callback, which @Legends pointed out then simply doesn't reference the script. Can you not create a script that processes after document load to handle what this script does (like loop through all elements you may need to change after the DOM is parsed)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot rearrange anything, all the HTML structure is generated by an external system which is closed source

Comment: @mark.hch is right. It's confirmed by the fact that, looking for other elements(e.g. `test.find('div')` or `test.find('p')`) we get _only those that are located above the `<script>`.

Comment: My suggestion then, if you can't rearrange the HTML, is to append a script instead at the end of body - something like `$('.control').each(function() {  $(this).find('input').val('something'); /* more code here */ });` otherwise, I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this with scripts embedded into the elements you want to manipulate, unless all the elements it needs to interact with are higher on the DOM, and therefore parsed when the script executes.

Comment: You said you can't rearrange _anything_? But in your OP you said " I have tried many variations of going down the tree": so you seem to be able to change the script itself, isn't it? If so, then you might merely replace `console.log($(test).find("input"));` by `$(document).ready(function() {console.log(test.find('input'));});`. I just checked it works this way.

Comment: I had given the document ready and load events a try, but these did not seem to work, instead I was able to add another item in my system below this div element that was able to access it above (Seeing as that part of the DOM would have been loaded as per @mark.hch 's comments)

Comment: I'm pretty surprised you couldn't have it working. Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a solution, but here is another way using basically the same code. You store the current script value in a variable, then reference that in a document ready callback:

```
<div id="p9t2c13">
   <div class="control">
      <label for="c13">
         <h3> HiddenInstanceId </h3>
         <p>
            <script>
               (function(){
                   var thisScript = $(document.currentScript);

                   $(function(){
                       var test = thisScript.closest("div").parent("div");
                       console.log($(test).find("input")) 
                   });
               })();
            </script>
         </p>
      </label>
      <p class="ctrlinvalidmessage"></p>
      <fieldset>
         <div class="input text">
            <input id="c13" type="text" name="c13" value="" maxlength="1000">
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have multiple instances of this script within the div and it seems to be only retrieving the last one though. It is still able to get set the last element though

Comment: Derp. You're absolutely right, I forgot to encapsulate it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Basically thisScript ended up as a global variable which was being overwritten, poor form on my part.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you wait for `$(document).ready()` before looking for something located below the current script.
Here it's working:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p9t2c13">
   <div class="control">
      <label for="c13">
         <h3> HiddenInstanceId </h3>
         <p>
            <script>
               if (typeof counter == "undefined") {
                  counter = 0;
               }

               counter++;

               var test = $(document.currentScript).closest("div").parent("div");
               // here is the change:
               $(document).ready(function() {console.log(test.find("input"));});
            </script>
         </p>
      </label>
      <p class="ctrlinvalidmessage"></p>
      <fieldset>
         <div class="input text">
            <input id="c13" type="text" name="c13" value="" maxlength="1000">
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```